# Cannot read SMS in KitKat, very confused

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

trying to get a very simple SMS broadcastreceiver working on my KitKat phone, but nothing is working. Driving me a little crazy. I don't need to do anything but read the SMS, so I don't think the big SMS changes in KitKat will affect me. I've read many posts, tried everything.

From what I've read I should only need SMS_DELIVER_ACTION to do a simple sniff of the text. I've put READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS in the manifest permissions. I have had it with JUST READ_SMS at first. I assume receive gives it to the app first, probably is short-circuited by KitKat "default" SMS behavior. BTW, nothing I've done will allow my app to show in the default sms system setting.

I have an incredibly simple app that has 1 activity, 1 broadcastreceiver class, and it's registered in the manifest. In onReceive I'm trying to write to LogCat and show a toast when a text comes in. Nothing ever hits that code.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.smoftware.smsreceivertest.app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SMSReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and my broadcastreceiver...

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SMSReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"in onReceive of SMSReceiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("SMSReceiver", "In body of onReceive method");
    }
}
```

I have a main activity but it's just a helloworld template. I made sure to have this because I've read about the 3.1 change that keeps a broadcastreceiver from running if not launched yet.

There shouldn't be any issue with this running in debug, should it? Even if so, I've stopped the app and relaunched so that it has been manually opened.

Thanks!

Comment: Change the `<intent-filter>` action to `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set receiver's `IntentFilter` as :

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">   
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought I had it setup this way at one point, but I guess not. I removed the RECEIVE_SMS permission as a test just now and it did not work. But with only RECEIVE_SMS is does. The android documentation says RECEIVE_SMS allows monitoring incoming SMS. So at least for my test that just writes to debug and shows a Toast, I only need RECEIVE_SMS. Cool.